# Handle check and uncheck checbox based on UserAction in HTML form

Tags: javascript

I need to handle check box status by storing a value like - Checkbox activated/deactivated in a HTML form using Javascript. During the initial form load, the check box status should not be captured. The status should be stored only when user selects and unselect it and the stored value should be displayed during revisit of the form. I am using below code, but it always shows the status - Deactived since my code validates it. How to handle this scenrio?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Updater() {
            var strOldText = document.getElementById("store").value;
            var strTexttoAdd = document.getElementById("commentsArea").value;
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var hours = currentDate.getHours();
            var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
            var strDate = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentDate.getDate() + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();
            var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
                       hours = hours % 12;
                       hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                       minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
            var strTime = strDate + '  ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
            var UserName = document.getElementById("CurrentUserRealName").value;
            var strNewLine = "<b>" + strTime + "</b>" + " - " + status  +  UserName +"<br>" + strTexttoAdd + "<p>";
            var strNewStore = strNewLine + strOldText;
            document.getElementById('store').value = strNewStore;
            document.getElementById("commentsArea").value = "";
            document.getElementById("hi_chbox_payment").value;                  
            if(document.getElementById("chbox_payment").checked)
            {
                document.getElementById("hi_chbox_payment").value="YES";
                                                    }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("hi_chbox_payment").value="NO";                             
            }
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
    <form method=post onsubmit="Updater()" name="NoteForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="store" name="store">
        <input type="hidden" id="INPUT" name="INPUT">
        <input type="hidden" id="hi_chbox_payment" name="hi_chbox_payment">     
        <input type="hidden" name="Itemnum" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="CurrentUserName" name="CurrentUserRealName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="OBDocumentType" value="1978">
        <p><font color="#000000" size="6">Instructions</font></p>
        Instructions Apply <input type="checkbox" id="chbox_payment">
    <input type=submit value=Save name=OBBtn_Yes> <br>          
        <br>

        <hr style="width:600px; text-align:left">
        <textarea id="commentsArea" rows=8 cols=72 value></textarea>
        <p><hr style="width:600px; text-align:left"><p>
            <table width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <font color=#000000>
                            <script>
                                document.write(document.getElementById('store').value); 
                                if(document.getElementById("hi_chbox_payment").value=="YES")
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("chbox_payment").checked = true;   
                                     var status = "Checkbox Activated by : " ;                                  
                                                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("chbox_payment").checked = false;   
                                          status = "Checkbox De-Activated by : " ;                                  
                                                                }
                            </script>
                        </font>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: how about using html5 local storage. set it to "YES" on checked even set it to "NO"on unchecked event.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Have tried it, but no luck. I missing something on validating the checkbox value during form load. Also it shouldn't capture text when user doesn't take any action on it eg. first saved the form with checked and he visited the form, but didn't take any action on checkbox. Our expectation is the stored value should not capture it as checkbox activated by..

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work using local storage.  try the fiddle below
https://jsfiddle.net/ne9mzw57/3/

when you first come in it says nothing (local storage is empty.) click the checkbox it says actived.  leave the page and come back to it, it still says active.

uncheck it and it says deactivated. leave the page and come back to it and it still says deactivated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
processCheckbox();
 $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       localStorage.setItem("checkbox", "YES");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("checkbox", "NO");
      }
      processCheckbox();
  });
});

function processCheckbox() {
  if (localStorage.checkbox) {
    if (localStorage.checkbox === 'YES') {
      $('#div1').text('Activated')
      $('#checkbox1').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#div1').text('Deactivated')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Could you please share the script using javascript as we need to it in html form for windows application